# Complexity of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o

So I have an algorithm that goes like this:

```
for i=0:360

 C...

 for j=0:a_j[i]

   C...

   for t=0:a_t[i][j]

     C...
   end
 end
end
```

So I have three loops but both inner loops depend on the value of the outer loops. How can I measure its Big O notation complexity?

Also what if I have memory asignments between these loops? Are they counted as Cs?

Comment: It's impossible to say, because we don't know what `a_j` and `a_t` are.

Comment: If this is basically `for i = 0 to 360; for j = 0 to i; for t = 0 to j;`, then complexity is `O(n ^ 3)`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Well... I guess they're arrays.

Comment: @H2CO3 Where did you find the `n`?

Comment: @H2CO3: Indeed.  But what's inside?

Comment: @H2CO3: That's the complexity class, not the complexity, right?

Comment: @thejh Well, `n ^ 3 - c1 * n ^ 2 - c2 * n`, but that asymptotically approaches `n ^ 3`.

Comment: and if I use the biggest a_j loop and biggest a_t loop? or would it be wrong to do it that way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not saying anything about the rest of the code, so assuming the rest is primitive operations of constant complexity.

If the entries of the two arrays are less than a constant value, then the complexity is `O(1)`-- the processing does not depend on any value input from outside your code. If they are functions of an input variable, then the complexity depends on the functions they are processed into those arrays and in this case you have to be more specific.

Comment: Ok I get it. The arrays do depend on an input variable. There are many operations done inside the innermost array. For example a sum of all the values of t into a result[i][j] and several others like that.

Comment: You have to be specific what those operns are. Depends still.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what `a_j` and `a_t` are exactly. If `a_j` and `a_t` are **constant**, then the complexity are `O(1)`. If `a_j` and `a_t` are the `n`, which may means input variables, then we have to compute the complexity.

In a word, the complexity of this program is decided by how you define `a_j` and `a_t`.

Anyway, I can compute how many loops that your program executes.

Here is the code written in python:

```
ret = 0
for i, v in a_j:
    ret += v * sum(a_t[i])
if not ret: ret = 1
ret *= 360
```

Hope it helps.